# SELECT Failed. 3504: Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group in v14.10.05.09 and not in v14.00.07.02

Tags: teradata

There are totally 9 fields in the select clause of the query where 5 are direct fields. 2 of them are result of select query in the select clause and 2 more are from using the result from previous 2 fields used in case when statements. The SUM aggregate is applied on the last two columns.

All the first 5 columns are listed in the group by clause.

Query :

```
SELECT
sub.a,sub.b,sub.c,Table1.d,Table1.e,

(select x from table t1 where y=current_date) as f,

(select z from table t1 where y=w) as g,

sum(case when f=g then 1 else 0)) as h,

sum(case when f+1=g then 1 else 0)) as i

FROM Table1

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT a,b,c,l,m,n,o FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table2.p=Table3.t)sub

ON Table1.e = sub.l

GROUP BY sub.a,sub.b,sub.c,Table1.d,Table1.e
```

The above query which works perfectly fine in Teradata v14.10.05.09 but fails with

> "SELECT Failed. 3504:  Selected non-aggregate values must be part of
>   the associated group"

in Teradata v14.00.07.02.

Is this because of something introduced in the newer version that is causing the query to fail but run fine in older version?
Or am I missing something?

Thanks in Advance.

This is the actual query that is giving the problem: `SELECT
  sub.key,sub.div,sub.reg_nm,tb_cal.calendar_yr,tb_cal.calendar_mth,
  (SEL  fiscal_yr FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal WHERE calendar_dt=CURRENT_DATE) current_fy,
  (SEL fiscal_yr FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal WHERE calendar_dt=clse_dt) clse_dt_fy,
  SUM(CASE WHEN current_fy=clse_dt_fy THEN sub.amt ELSE 0 END) cnt
FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal

 LEFT JOIN(  SELECT
   tbl_a.key,tbl_a.stage,COALESCE(tbl_u.div, 'Un-assigned') div,COALESCE(tbl_u.reg_nm,'Un-assigned') reg_nm,tbl_a.clse_dt,tbl_a.amt
  FROM db_a.tbl_a tbl_a
  INNER JOIN  db1.tbl_u tbl_u

   ON tbl_u.unit_key=tbl_a.unit_key
  WHERE tbl_a.ctg IN ('G','O','C','F','I') AND tbl_a.stage NOT IN ('R', 'D', 'N','A') AND tbl_a.ind = 0 
)sub
ON sub.clse_dt =  tb_cal.calendar_dt
GROUP BY sub.key,sub.div,sub.reg_nm,tb_cal.calendar_yr,tb_cal.calendar_mth`

Comment: you should also include f and g in the group by clause. @nhm

Comment: But adding f and g query would give me different result for the sum. The computation of the sum would go wrong. I wonder how the same query works fine in one instance of Teradata and fails in another. Is there anything i else i can do in order to achieve the same functionality

Comment: Try changing the Scalar Subqueries to a MIN: `(select MIN(z) from table t1...)`. Btw, adding f and g to GROUP BY should not change the result, both seem to have no correlation... Can you show the actual code of `where y=w`?

Comment: adding MIN to scalar sub queries gave another error. the code for y=w is as follows: SEL fiscal_yr FROM db.tbl1 WHERE calendar_dt=colse_dt

Comment: Which error? `SEL fiscal_yr FROM db.tbl1 WHERE calendar_dt=colse_dt`, is this returning a single value, both `calendar_dt` and  `colse_dt` are columns from `db.tbl1`? Or is it correlated to one of the GROUP BY columns? The full source code would be helpful, otherwise it's hard to tell if 14 or 14.10 is doing it wrong...

Comment: @dnoeth: i have edited the question to have the original query at the end of it. Could you please take a look at it and help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `clse_dt` is a column from `db1.tb_cal` then `clse_dt_fy` is a constant like `current_fy`. In that case the query must return the same result when you add both columns to GROUP BY. If it's not a constant the error message is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        SELECT
                      sub.key,
                      sub.div,
                      sub.reg_nm,
                      tb_cal.calendar_yr,
                      tb_cal.calendar_mth,
                      (SEL  fiscal_yr FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal WHERE calendar_dt=CURRENT_DATE) current_fy,
                      (SEL fiscal_yr FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal WHERE calendar_dt=clse_dt) clse_dt_fy,
                      SUM(CASE WHEN current_fy=clse_dt_fy THEN sub.amt ELSE 0 END) cnt
                    FROM db1.tb_cal tb_cal
                     LEFT JOIN(  SELECT
                       tbl_a.key,tbl_a.stage,COALESCE(tbl_u.div, 'Un-assigned') div,COALESCE(tbl_u.reg_nm,'Un-assigned') reg_nm,tbl_a.clse_dt,tbl_a.amt
                      FROM db_a.tbl_a tbl_a
                      INNER JOIN  db1.tbl_u tbl_u
                       ON tbl_u.unit_key=tbl_a.unit_key
                      WHERE tbl_a.ctg IN ('G','O','C','F','I') AND tbl_a.stage NOT IN ('R', 'D', 'N','A') AND tbl_a.ind = 0 
                    ) sub
                    ON sub.clse_dt =  tb_cal.calendar_dt
                    GROUP BY sub.key,sub.div,sub.reg_nm,tb_cal.calendar_yr,tb_cal.calendar_mth,current_fy,clse_dt_fy;
```

This should work fine. But as per your comments, you said adding the last to columns in group by would alter your required answer. If that is the case, you can post what is your desired result set. We can help you out in that. Although looking at your query it doesn't seem that adding current_fy and clse_dt_fy will change your current result set.